# Manipulate VARCHAR string and update column (pseudo-date)

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sql-update, varchar

So long story short, a client of mine wanted to change a date-time field into a varchar field, after hours of telling them why they should not do that, I finally gave in.

My Issue is the dates now converted into VARCHAR are `yyyy-mm-dd` and I need to flip them around into `mm-dd-yyyy` I can do this with PHP with a `foreach()` loop and a `list()=explode()` but is there a way to do it with a sql query?

Comment: Use the SUBSTRING function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DATE_FORMAT`:

```
UPDATE your_table SET your_varchar = DATE_FORMAT(your_varchar ,'%m-%d-%Y')
```

For more information, see the MySQL documentation: [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: Well that worked exactly as intended. So MySQL can understand it as a date without being set to date? I'll have to read up on DATE_FORMAT. Also it wont let me select your answer for another 5 minutes :p

Comment: Exactly, MySQL takes a string as a date for any of the Date/Time functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(date_to_change,9,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(date_to_change,6,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(date_to_change,1,4)
...
```

See if that's what you're looking for.

Apologies - forgot to add the rest of it on.

```
UPDATE 
    table_to_update 
SET 
    date_to_change = SUBSTRING(date_to_change,9,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(date_to_change,6,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(date_to_change,1,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
SELECT CAST(DATE_FORMAT(dateColumn, '%m-%d-%Y') AS CHAR(10));
```